# Gorm V1 vs V2 differences

Tags: database, postgresql, go, orm, grails-orm

Can anyone explain the difference between Gorm v1 and Gorm v2 using dialects?
I've been reusing code from the previous project, which worked with Gorm v1, where it was querying the dialect `gorm.GetDialect()` from dsn.Hostname, and applying it via `gorm.RegisterDialect()`.
There are no such methods in Gorm 2, and I'm puzzled about what these are for anyways.
Seems that if these has been removed, then we don't need them anyways, right?

Comment: i think best way is read documentation

Comment: Agree. I was going over the gorm.io/docs but couldn't find anything related to that particular change.

Comment: is it useful for u? https://dev.to/evillord666/gorm-level-up-how-to-upgrade-and-start-to-use-gorm-v2-31dj

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to make that switch before, just wanted to figure if I was using the new open() correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Gorm V2, the DB connection is changed to

```golang
import (
  "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
  "gorm.io/gorm"
)

dsn := "host=localhost user=gorm password=gorm dbname=gorm port=9920 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai"
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
```

The code of [`gorm.Open`](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/master/gorm.go#L116) initialize db session based on **dialector**, which is replaced with `gorm.RegisterDialect()`

```golang
// Open initialize db session based on dialector
func Open(dialector Dialector, opts ...Option) (db *DB, err error) {
    config := &Config{}
```

More V2 API details please refer to https://gorm.io/docs/

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I've searched in the docs, but I wasn't able to find any info via doc search in regard to that matter. So, if I understood you correctly the registerDialect is not needed, since we are using Open() now, which in turn accepts dialector, and the creation of this dialector is the same as gorm.GetDialect() now, right? Then how do we create the dialector for Postgres for example?

Comment: @Igor, just update my answer for Postgres connection. hope it could help you

Comment: Oh, it's that simple. Yepp, that's answers my question